# Error message not reproduced at reevaluation, SetDelayed cache?

Tags: warning-messages, kernel, assignment

Mathematica v13.0:

```
nr:=HoldForm@Evaluate@Function[t,x@t][]
```

then evaluate

```
In[29]:= nr
During evaluation of In[29]:= Function::fpct: Too many parameters in {t} to be filled from Function[t,x[t]][].
Out[29]= Function[t,x[t]][]
```

Strangely, reevaluation does not reproduce the error message:

```
In[30]:= nr
Out[30]= Function[t,x[t]][]
```

although reevaluating `Function[t,x[t]][]` reproduces the error message, hence `SetDelayed` is responsible for the non reproduction of the error message and more precisely it must be caching something.

Same problem with `nr:=HoldForm@Evaluate@Transpose@{{1},{1,2}}`.

However, no problem with `nr:=HoldForm@Evaluate[1/0]` and `nr:=HoldForm@Evaluate[n:=n+1;n]`.

What is going on?  How to always obtain an error message at each evaluation?

Comment: This is cheating but produces an error every time: `nr := ToExpression["Function[t,x@t][]"]`

Answer (score 7):

We can cause the message to appear every time by calling `Update[]` in the body of the definition:

```
ClearAll[nr]
nr := (Update[]; HoldForm@Evaluate@Function[t, x@t][])
```

[image: example showing that the message occurs every call]

---

**Details**

It would appear that this is one of those "special circumstances" referred to in the documentation of [Update](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Update.html.en):

> `Update` manipulates internal optimization features of the Wolfram Language. It should not need to be called except under special circumstances that rarely occur in practice.

In support of this conjecture, a call to `Update` will cause the message to recur:

[image: use of Update[] to clear an internal cache]

Interestingly, the internal cache does not appear to be associated with the symbol `nr`.  Rather, it is associated with `Function`:

[image: updating nr does not clear the cache]

(note: `Unevaluated[nr]` is necessary because `Update` does not hold its arguments and `nr` has an own-value.)

We can reproduce this behaviour even in the absence of the special evaluation rules that apply to `HoldForm`, `Evaluated` and `Function`:

[image: simpler example]

Comment: I did not know about `Update`, great trick.

Answer (score 2):

This behavior can be obtained with any defined function, when the right hand side of its definition is not used.  A minimal example:

```
ClearAll@function;
function::fpct:="function error"
function[]/;Message[function::fpct]:=whatever
```

then try `nr:=HoldForm@Evaluate@function[];nr;nr` (only one error message).

It can also be forced on any function by caching like this: `nr:=(nr=HoldForm@Evaluate[1/0]);nr;nr` (only one error message) as opposed to `nr:=HoldForm@Evaluate[1/0];nr;nr` (two error messages).

To always obtain an error message, one could try something like:

```
ClearAll@function
function::fpct:="function error"
function[]/;(Message[function::fpct];True):=function[]
```

now with `nr:=HoldForm@Evaluate@function[]`, `nr` produces at least one error message at each evaluation.

Actually, the first evaluation of `nr` produces TWO error messages.

Independently of `nr`, the first evaluation of `function[]` produces two errors messages but the reevaluation produces only one error message.

Double error message at first evaluation can be avoided like this:

```
ClearAll@function
function::fpct:="function error"
firstRun=True;
function[]/;(If[Not@firstRun,Message[function::fpct],firstRun=False];True):=function[]
```

but this method may lead to further problems, related to the variable `firstRun` or the redefinition of Wolfram language proper functions like Function, Transpose.